# Searching standard commands for a string

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to list all the standard commands that contain a certain string. I'm told echo $PATH will help with this but I'm not sure how... Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `man find` will definitely help you. Try something like `find /usr/bin -iname \*string\*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`` find `echo $PATH | tr : ' ' ` | grep FOO ``

Where "FOO" is the string you're interested in.

And if you want to ignore case, use the `-i` flag for `grep`:

`` find `echo $PATH | tr : ' ' ` | grep -i FOO ``

Answer (score 0):

```
ls `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'` | grep "string_to_search_for"
```

Answer (score 0):

All the "standard commands" will be located in /bin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/something/bin, etc. So all the commands have a "bin/" in front of them. Just let `locate` do its thing:

```
locate bin/ | grep -F 'whatever you are looking for'
```

Actually, /sbin and /usr/sbin will contain system commands. If you want to exclude those:

```
locate bin/ | grep -F sbin/ | grep -F 'whatever you are looking for'
```

All you want to know about the different bin and sbin directories can be found in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure).